# Beautiful Soup - Loop Through Navigable String

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to loop through a NavigableString and grab all the content within the 'a' tags.  I did a

```
home= items.findAll('div', class_="dlineups-half")
```

and it gets me the NaviableString below.  I can get the first piece of data via home.a.contents which gives me Joe Bendik, but whenever I run any type of loop to get all the .a.contents I get a 'NavigableString' object has no attribute.  My question is how do I go about looping through a NavigableString and grabbing all the a.contents.

```
<div class="dlineups-half"><div class="dlineups-vplayer"><div
class="dlineups-pos">G</div><div><a href="/soccer/player.htm?id=18688"
  title="Joe Bendik">Joe Bendik</a></div><div class="dlineups-vplayer"> 
<div class="dlineups-pos">D</div><div><a href="/soccer/player.htm?
id=9368"title="David Mateos">David Mateos</a>...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find all `a` elements inside and [get the text](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text):

```
home = items.find_all('div', class_="dlineups-half")
for item in home:
    for a in item.find_all("a"):
        print(a.get_text())
```